# Data not displayed in popup (Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, popup

I'm coding a chrome extension. I select the words in content.js and save my selections by clicking on contextMenu. I send the saved words to popup.js with the "chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'sendArray', arr: arr })". The problem is that no data is visible in popup.js console and popup.html. But there is an exception. If I select a word and save it while the popup is open, then it appears.
How can I solve this problem?

**popup.js**

```html
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  let wordList = document.getElementById('wordList');

  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
      if (request.action === 'sendArray') {
        var receivedArray = request.arr;
        
        wordList.innerHTML = "";

        receivedArray.forEach((data) => {
          let listItem = document.createElement('li');
          listItem.textContent = data;
          wordList.appendChild(listItem);
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

**content.js**

```html
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  var selectedWord = window.getSelection().toString().trim();

  if (request.action === 'saveSelectedWord') {
    chrome.storage.local.get({ key: [] }, function (result) {
      let arr = result.key || [];
  
      arr.push(selectedWord);
    
      chrome.storage.local.set({ key: arr }, function () {
        console.log("Value is set", arr);
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'sendArray', arr: arr });
      });
  
      console.log(arr);
    });
  }
});
```

**background.js**

```html
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function () {
  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: 'Seçilen Sözcüğü Kaydet',
    contexts: ['selection'],
    id: 'saveSelectedWord'
  });
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function (info, tab) {
  if (info.menuItemId === 'saveSelectedWord') {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { action: 'saveSelectedWord' });
  }
});
```

Comment: Use [sidePanel](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/sidePanel/) instead of the popup.

Answer (score 0):

Because javascript in the `popup.js` file only works when the popup existed a.k.a it is opened. To use data selected by the `content.js`, I suggest saving them using [Chrome Extension Storage](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/storage). After saving the data in the storage, you can get them out everytime you open the popup by retrieve them at the start of the script.

Comment: Hi, yes I am using chrome storage in content.js to save words. Should I do the get event in popup.js? Thanks..

Comment: @astana25 In my opinion, you shouldn't and probably couldn't also since there is no official way to keep the extension `popup` open when interacting with the website. If you really want to have some kind of `popup` to keep track of the whole usage (the current words, etc.), you can open the extension `popup` page as a whole new popup window using [chrome.windows.create](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/windows#method-create)  with `url` as your chrome extension popup urls